# Using random extension for HTML5 video playback

Tags: html, video, html5-video, mp4

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" preload="none">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="myvideo.randomextension" />
</video>
```

Will this video be played on all mp4 supported browsers? As I changed the video extension from ".mp4" to ".randomextension".?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should work, as long as the web server provides the correct Content-Type header. If you're writing the server yourself, in python or node.js or something like that, it's simple enough. If you're using an existing web server, you'll have to do some configuration, because those servers typically use the file extension to know which content type to use.

For example, if your web server is Apache, you might add a line like this to your .htaccess file:

```
AddType video/mp4 .randomextension
```